# Parse date in c# the same way as it works in javascript..?

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I'm developing an electron application with typescript and another backend application with c#. Now i'm trying to parse data from .xlsx Files in my electron app (javascript), and almost the same kind of data trough an XML API from my c# application in the backend..

Now the thing is, the receiving data has a timestamp formatted like this:

```
2021-07-22T11:31:43Z
```

Now, when i parse this date in javascript by doing this:

```
moment.locale('de')
const date = moment('2021-07-22T11:31:43Z', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss') // haha i'm not even using the correct format to parse this... moment still works magically
const myDate = date.format() // format without params will return ISO 8601, no fractional seconds
// myDate will be = "2021-07-22T11:31:43+02:00"
```

Javascript seems to add the timezone information of my personal computer i'm running the code with (and adds this "+02:00" at the end..)

Now, i try to do the same thing with c#:

```
var timestampDate = DateTime.Parse("2021-07-22T11:31:43Z");
var myDate = timestampDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
// myDate will be = "2021-07-22T11:31:43.000Z"
```

I just get the date as it was in the input. Well, i think c# is doing a better job here as i don't say anything about timezone's in the parsing command. But well, i guess i'm miss-using moment a little bit in my example above.

Now the problem - when i store the date-string coming from javascript, the UI will display the correct time "11:31". When i store the date-string from c#, it will display "13:31". So, i think i should achieve the same thing in c# as i do in javascript, but how?

Comment: edited the text to remove swearing, sry

Answer (score 2):

The format is ISO-8601. You're *already* getting the date/time in your local timezone because `DateTime` defaults to local, it's just you converted it to "universal" time explicitly in your code.

To get the same format of output, [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) you can use the `"O"` format string:

```
var timestampDate = DateTime.Parse("2021-07-22T11:31:43Z");
var isoString = timestampDate.ToString("O");
```

On my local machine, which is GMT+01:00 on that date, I get:

```
2021-07-22T12:31:43.0000000+01:00
```

If you want to tweak the format, you can use a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) instead (`"K"` for the timezone indicator, for instance, don't hardcode `Z` which is for GMT), but as you can see it has the timezone correct and has appropriately adjusted the hour to account for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve but based on javascript code : moment.locale('de')
what wants to get is local time for any country even if the code runs from an outside machine ?

if this is what you want , you could do it with function like this :

```
 public string DateTimeNowInGermany()

    {

        var info = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Germany Standard Time");
        System.DateTimeOffset localServerTime = System.DateTimeOffset.Now;
        System.DateTimeOffset localTime = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localServerTime, info);

        return localTime.DateTime.ToString();
    }
```

Just change the country name for any targeted country.

but if you want to get local only of machine time , something like :

```
  public  DateTime ChangeDateFormat(string str)

    {

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(str);
                
        return dt;
    }
```

you could remove T , Z letters before inputting the date string ...

If the above didn't solve your problem , explain what's your problem it's local or remote time ...